# Combine multiple rows into single row for csv

Tags: sql, csv, snowflake-cloud-data-platform

I'm joining together two tables which I'm using for employment records.  I need to combine into one row employees which have multiple positions and only a few columns which specify those other positions.  For example:

| Employee Name | Job | Building | ID |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| Suzy Q | Baker | Kitchen | 2 |
| Suzy Q | Nun | Church | 2 |

Desired Output

| Employee Name | Job | Building | ID |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| Suzy Q | Baker, Nun | Kitchen, Church | 2 |

I'm a bit at a loss on how to identify in the list of employees how someone is a duplicate.  The DB in this case is Snowflake, if it makes a difference.  My educated guess is somehow find duplicates in the ID and then concat the results for the duplicate into the job and building fields, but I'm open to suggestions.

Answer (score -1):

Try using the [LISTAGG](https://docs.snowflake.com/en/sql-reference/functions/listagg) function

Answer (score -1):

While LISTAGG is a clause that could be used for this problem - this clause is only available in Oracle.

The PostgreSQL equivalent for this clause is **STRING_AGG**. You can try the below to generate the desired output - this works by aggregating all entries for both **Job** and **Building** into a single string. GROUP BY is then used to aggregate all entries by employee name into a single, comma-separated string.

```
SELECT employee_name, STRING_AGG (job,', '), STRING_AGG (building,', ') FROM table group by employee_name;
```

Comment: The question was tagged with Snowflake and LISTAGG is available in Snowflake and I even linked to it in the Snowflake documentation. I’m not sure why you are bringing up PostgreSQL ?